# how to autoload the menu bar in emacs

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

I have installed YaSnippet in my emacs. Every time I start emacs, I have to turn on the menu bar manually by M-x menu-bar-mode, how do I load it by default ?

Also strangely the YaSnippet menu shows up the first time the menu bar comes up, however after I move to another buffer and back, I cant see the menu anymore ! How do I get it back without restarting emacs?

Comment: evidently you are using an emacs config sourced from elsewhere. go through the config at least and try to familiarize yourself with what is going on in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu bar is loaded by default in emacs. Therefore if you have to turn in on in every buffer it means that you have disabled it in your init file. Remove a line that would say something like `(menu-bar-mode 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

To start `menu-bar-mode` automatically, just put `(menu-bar-mode 1)` in your `~/.emacs`

I'm afraid your yasnippet problem is outside of my realm of lore :(